# Getting Django REST Framework's HyperlinkedModelSerializer to recognize non-default routes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am in the early stages of a project using Django, Django REST Framework, and SQL. **I am very new to DRF.**

I have a model that tracks user info for a game service that runs different servers for regions of the world (ex. NA, EU, etc). User IDs are only unique per-region, but the users are all stored using the same model (table). I am employing `unique_together = ('user_id', 'region')` in my model's Meta class to ensure there are no duplicates. *Please note that, as such, the PKs in the DB are not related to the user IDs.*

DRF, by default, would create endpoints using the DB's PKs of Users, but I have changed that to use a system like `/users/na/123` to get the object where `user_id = 123` and `region = 'na'` (north america). A snippet for this from urls.py follows:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<region>.+)/$', UserList.as_view()),
url(r'^users/(?P<region>.+)/(?P<user_id>.+$)', UserDetail.as_view()),
```

These are generic views (generics.ListAPIView and generics.RetrieveAPIView), respectfully.

Currently, the rest of my views are ViewSets.

One of the things I model is historical match data, where users are related to by a Game model, to keep track of who participated in a match like so:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    player_1 = models.ForeignKey(User)
    player_2 = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I plan on implementing a route for games like I did w/users (again, game_id is unique only per-region) so I can do `/game/<region>/<game_id>`.

**My question is this:**

How can I get hyperlinks to Users using my established `/user/<region>/<user_id>` routes in Game list/detail views on the API?

Presently, my GameSerializer is defined as follows:

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        exclude = ('id',)
```

When I change it to a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` I get the following error upon visiting the Game endpoints:

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "user-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in
>   your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
>   this field.

I assume this is because my User endpoints are implemented differently than what it expects (it can't know I have abandoned the default PK indexing method and opted for a custom route a la `/users/<region>/<user_id>` instead of `/users/<pk>`, right?)

How do I approach this problem? I would be open to suggestions that are extraneous to the DRF side of things, like restructuring my DB/Django models, if it seems like the direction I want things to go is crazy (not wanting to use PKs).

Comment: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1024 this is a a bit dated, but makes me think there is no "recommended" solution at the moment. :(

Answer (score 1):

After a few more days of reading and thinking about the problem differently, it looks `Meta.unique_together` is kind of like expressing a composite key in SQL. This lead me to this solution:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-rest-framework/tHmEAzSNgG4

> e.g. instead of using an URL like this to identify an employee:
>
> `api/1.3/employee/5/`
>
> I use an URL like this:
>
> `api/1.3/company/23/employee/5/`
>
> I use a HyperlinkedModelSerializer to serialise this model.  I
>   couldn't find a way of configuring a HyperlinkedIdentityField to
>   handle the composite key (you can only specify a single lookup_field)
>   so I override the url with a SerializerMethodField instead, like this:
>
> ```
> class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
>    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_employee_detail_url')
>
>
>    def get_employee_detail_url(self, obj):
>        # generate the URL for the composite key
>        ...
>        return composite_key_url
> ```

Still exploring my options, but this looks pretty clean.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up against the same problem today. After going through the Django-Rest-Framework documentation on Generic views I came across:

lookup_field - The model field that should be used to for performing object lookup of individual model instances. Defaults to 'pk'. Note that when using hyperlinked APIs you'll need to ensure that both the API views and the serializer classes set the lookup fields if you need to use a custom value.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views

In my case I did this in my models.py

```
class UserDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = "username"
```

...and works lovely now. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks you but this only relates to the situation where a single field is looked up. I need to retrieve based on what is effectively a "composite key", that is, 2 fields of my model, taken together, are unique to the table (region and user ID).

Comment: oh yes, sorry, I should have read your question properly. I like the solution you posted below.